# Django page not found - general

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

What is the difference between Django's two options:

- return HttpRequestNotFound()
- raise Http404

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Returning `HttpRequestNotFound` means that the view takes care of presenting the 404 page and its HTML. You can use this if you want a view to present a different 404 error page than the default Django 404 page.
- Raising `Http404` means Django will use the default 404 view that you've configured (by default this is `django.views.defaults.page_not_found`). This can be modified by specifying a different handler for 404 pages (see [`django.conf.urls.handler404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404)).

For more details see Django's [documentation on 404 error pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).